# How do you say you accept something wrong being done?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How do you say when you are NOT doing anything wrong, but you are part of it by not pointing out the crime/situation....

e.g.: You are married to your wife and she starts to get fatter....the fatter she gets, the sadder you became ....and you do not say anything about it so you are ___________.

The word missing is the one I need.

In portuguese we have the word

> "Conivente"

which fits perfectly.

However, in English I am not sure about what to use.

Comment: Would *complicit* work for you?

Comment: @deadrat *Complicit* doesn't work in this case because the OP included the point that "you are not doing anything wrong." Being *complicit* means that you are involved in the crime/wrongdoing rather than just being aware of it.

Comment: *an accessory to the crime*, an *enabler*.

Comment: @pyobum You're right for *complicit* as a legal term of art, since under the law, to be complicit in an illegal act is to be an accomplice of a law- breaker, which in itself is criminal act. In the vernacular, I find uses of the word to mean involved with or approving of a bad act in such a way that cannot accrue blame for the bad act.

Comment: @deadrat The OED agrees with you. Its definition for *complicit* as of 2005 (3d ed.): "Involved knowingly or with passive compliance, often in something underhand, sinister, or illegal."

Comment: @1006a Stopped clock and all that. Thanks.

Comment: @Adriano - Are you looking for a noun, verb or adjective?

Comment: In portuguese it is both adjective and substantive. I guess an adjective works fine.

Comment: Check out "tacit".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though *you are NOT doing anything wrong* but NOT *pointing out the crime/situation*, as you say, does make you a [**conniver**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conniver).

Also according to MW:

> 1
>   :  to pretend ignorance of or fail to take action against something one ought to oppose
>  
>  **Eg**:
>
> - The government *connived* in the rebels' military buildup.
> - The principal *connived* at all the school absences that were recorded on the day of the city's celebration of its Super Bowl victory

Comment: I had no idea that was a valid meaning of "connive" ... I thought it was about scheming and collaborating bad deeds!

Comment: Connive does have more of a mischievous edge.

Comment: Interestingly, Google translate lists "Conniving" as the English equivalent of Portuguese "Conivente"

Comment: @MichaelJ.That indeed is interesting. Somehow when I read 'conviente', connive was the first word that struck in my head.

Answer (score 13):

Rather than a single word, the common expression "turning a blind eye" would suit this situation.

From the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye), "turning a blind eye":

> To ignore something and pretend you do not see it. How can you turn a blind eye to all those starving children?
>
> To choose to ignore behaviour that you know is wrong. I knew Hugo was taking the money but I turned a blind eye because he was my sister's child. (often + to ) Management often turn a blind eye to bullying in the workplace.

Answer (score 10):

You are *acquiescing*. That is, you are tacitly approving or otherwise permitting the inference of consent absent explicit objection.

Answer (score 5):

e.g.

> The parents became accessory to the murder, when they helped their son escape the country.

> ....the fatter she gets, the sadder you became ....and you do not say anything about it, and so you are an accessory to her ill-health. You are accessorial to her ill-health.

---

[ac·ces·so·ry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accessory)  (ăk-sĕs′ə-rē)
n. pl. ac·ces·so·ries

1. - a. A subordinate or supplementary item; an adjunct.
   - b. Something nonessential but desirable that contributes to an effect or result. See Synonyms at attachment.
2. Law - One who knowingly assists a lawbreaker in the commission of a crime but does not actually participate in that crime.
   adj.
3. Having a secondary, supplementary, or subordinate function.
4. Law - Involving the knowing assistance of a lawbreaker in the commission of a crime without actual participation in the crime.

[Middle English accessorie, from Medieval Latin accessōrius, from accessor, helper, from Latin accessus, approach; see access.]

ac′ces·so′ri·al (-sə-sôr′ē-əl) adj.

ac·ces′so·ri·ly adv.

Usage Note: Although the pronunciation (ə-sĕs′ə-rē), with no (k) sound in the first syllable, is sometimes heard, it is not accepted by a majority of the Usage Panel. In the 1997 survey, 87 percent of the Panelists disapproved of it. The 2012 survey showed an 80 percent disapproval rate.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

---

Synonyms:

accessory

noun

1. A subordinate element added to another entity:
   adjunct, appendage, appurtenance, attachment, supplement.
2. One who assists a lawbreaker in a wrongful or criminal act:
   accomplice, confederate, conspirator.

adjective

Giving or able to give help or support:
ancillary, assistant, auxiliary, collateral, contributory, subsidiary, supportive.

*The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus. Copyright © 2013, 2014 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Comment: For the people on the other side of the pond, the word is apparently, _accesary_.

Answer (score 5):

You're *complicit by omission*.

An example from the Washington Post:

> Other Republican leaders remain mostly silent, hiding behind the excuse that attacking Mr. Trump might only help him. They must ask themselves whether they want to be **complicit by omission** in his poisoning of American political life.

Comment: You should find a more neutral quote. I'm tired of seeing political references in unrelated questions. Maybe include a definition, also.

Answer (score 4):

One is ***resigned*** when accepting such situations without resistance.

> ....and you do not say anything about it so you are ***resigned***.

ODO:

> **[resigned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resigned)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Having accepted something unpleasant that one cannot do anything
>   about:
>   ‘my response is a resigned shrug of the shoulders’
>
> ‘Instead of being outraged, many ranchers seemed resigned.’

Answer (score 4):

I am frankly amazed that nobody has yet pointed out that you are [condoning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/condone) your wife's behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with just _condoning_ since that implies you're OK with it, which the OP clearly states he is not.

Comment: @JATerroba: if you do not say anything about the behaviour, you are absolutely condining it, whatevr your feelings may be.

Answer (score 2):

***Negligent***

neg·li·gent  ˈneɡləjənt/  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=negligent%20dictionary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

```
failing to take proper care in doing something.
"directors have been negligent in the performance of their duties"
```

You neglected to say anything about her condition, and therefore you feel guilt about it.  You are guilty of negligence.

Also, definition from [Miriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negligent):

1a :  marked by or given to neglect especially habitually or culpably

1b :  failing to exercise the care expected of a reasonably prudent person in like circumstances

2 :  marked by a carelessly easy manner

Comment: I would choose this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The word **abide** works here.

The most pertinent definitions for **abide** from [Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abide):

> 1 to bear patiently
>
> 2 to accept without objection

In your example, exactly as it is worded:

> You are married to your wife and she starts to get fatter....the fatter she gets, the sadder you became ....and you do not say anything about it so you are *abiding*.

We usually use *abide* in this way by following it with the behavior/situation being abided (i.e. abide X):

> Your wife starts getting fatter and fatter. The fatter she gets, the sadder you become, but you do not say anything--you are abiding her weight gain.

Usage example from [biographical information on Robert Frost](http://www.frostfriends.org/sanfrancisco.html) discussing his father [italics mine]:

> Isabelle soon knew another side of Will Frost as a drinker and gambler, traits he had acquired at Harvard. He could be a harsh man to live with, but she *abided his habits* as a dutiful wife who relied on her own strong religious faith.

Answer (score 1):

The husband in your example is being an [enabler](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enabler), or is enabling his wife:

> one that enables another to achieve an end; *especially* :  one who enables another to persist in self-destructive behavior (as substance abuse) by providing excuses or by making it possible to avoid the consequences of such behavior

(link and definition from Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 0):

***Condone*** is a good verb to use when you intentionally overlook a detail like your wife's voracious eating habits and gain in weight.

Someone who condones can be called a ***condoner***, but the word doesn't appear in all dictionaries. So I am not sure of its usage.

Answer (score -3):

You can `put up` with the thing, `live with it` and\or `tolerate`it.

All of these phrases would imply that you didn't like the thing, but weren't going to try to change\correct it.