# What is dealing with an uncomfortable/unacceptable situation called?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is it called when someone isn't okay with a situation but learns to just deal with it? Is there even a word for that?

Comment: *Tolerate* might fit. See [Oxford definition 1.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tolerate)

Comment: Related thread...[How do you say you accept something wrong being done] https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368016/how-do-you-say-you-accept-something-wrong-being-done/368062#368062

Comment: I think  you need to include more details. Otherwise, it could be lots of things—compromising, settling, being a grown-up, giving up, etc. What terms have you considered, and why don't they work? Why doesn't "dealing with it" work for you? At a minimum, you should include a sample sentence showing how you would use the word, with a ___ or other placeholder where the word would go. That will help make your meaning clearer, and is also technically [required for single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 2):

***The person learns how to cope with the situation.***

**cope,** from [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cope): '

> 1. intransitive verb   If you cope with a problem or task, you deal with it successfully.
>
> It was amazing how my mother coped with bringing up three children on
>   less than
>
> thirty dollars a week.
>
> 2. intransitive verb   If you have to cope with an unpleasant situation, you have to accept it or bear it.
>
> Never before has the industry had to cope with war and recession at
>   the same time

Answer (score 1):

**Acquiesce** -
verb

To accept something reluctantly but without protest.
 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce

Comment: Where did you get that definition from? If you edit a link into your answer, it helps us confirm it.

Comment: It's a word I learned years ago. Merriam-Webster gives a similar definition: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce

Comment: If you look at [the other answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403394/194281), by a high-rep user, you'll see they give a link to the dictionary in the answer. You can [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/403396/edit) your post to add your Merriam-Webster link in...

Comment: Happy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is called ***contending*** (with that situation).

ODO:

> **[contend](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/contend)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1** (contend for) [no object]   Struggle to surmount (a difficulty or danger)
>   ‘she had to contend with his uncertain temper’
>
> ‘Not only are they contending with the sudden drop in temperatures,
>   one was shot with an arrow and one lost its home.’